# VBA: How to merge duplicate data in a single array/dictionary and return values?

Tags: vba, macros, coreldraw

I've written a VBA macro for CorelDraw that loops through selected objects and returns values as a string. I want it to be able to handle duplicate data better, for example if two objects have the same size, it should return

```
"2 of 10 x 10"
```

instead of

```
"1 of 10 x 10"
"1 of 10 x 10"
```

Coming from Ruby (specifically thinking of hashes), I'm thinking that the macro should loop through the selected range, add (object.sizeWidth, object.sizeHeight) data as strings to an array/dictionary where it should be checked for duplicates and count them. I don't know what's best or how to set/check their values.

Here is my code so far

```
Sub objectsToString()

Dim str As String
Dim v As Shape, vr As ShapeRange
Dim xSize#, ySize#
Dim dupCount As Integer

str = ""
Set vr = ActiveSelectionRange

   For Each v In vr
   dupCount = 'value assigned via iteration
   xSize = v.SizeWidth
   ySize = v.SizeHeight
   str = str & dupCount & " of " & xSize & " x " & ySize & vbNewLine

Next v

End Sub
```

Comment: " I'm thinking that the macro should loop through the selected range, add (object.sizeWidth, object.sizeHeight) data as strings to an array/dictionary " - yes, that's correct. You need to use a dictionary (can find plenty of examples online), there you can check if the specific dimensions were already used, if not add them, if yes, increase the number of their occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have CorelDraw myself, but here's a comparable example:

```
' Set up some sample items
Dim items(2) As String
items(0) = "10 x 10"
items(1) = "20 x 20"
items(2) = "10 x 10"

' Create a dictionary to store the items and count
' Key: [n] x [n]
' Value: Count of item
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each Item In items
    If dict.Exists(Item) Then
        ' Increase existing count
        dict(Item) = dict(Item) + 1
    Else
        ' Add new item to dictionary and set count to 1
        dict.Add Item, 1
    End If
Next

' Print dictionary
For Each Key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print dict(Key) & " of " & Key
Next
```

If you haven't done so already, you need to add a reference to the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library in the Tools → References dialog. If that library is not in the list, use the browse button to select `C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll`.